# C++ program crashing for a string concatenation.

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, segmentation-fault, memcpy

This is the line that is causing the crash :

```
if (size <= 0)
        return;
    if (data)
    {
        std::string sData = std::string((char*)data, size);
        buffer += sData;  <-- This is the line causing crash
        processBuffer();
    }
    else
        return;
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread -1282016352 (LWP 27952)]
0x002b48ec in memcpy () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x002b48ec in memcpy () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x001fea31 in std::string::_Rep::_M_clone () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x001fef2e in std::string::reserve () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x001ff83d in std::string::append () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x001ff9e2 in std::string::operator+= () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x003fc6c8 in StreamDecoder::StreamDecoderEncoder::addData 
    at src/StreamDecoder.cpp:171
```

I have verified that `data` is not empty and buffer is a string declared as a private member variable of that class.

I do not know why there is a segfault on memcpy. What could have gone wrong here ?

Comment: Try valgrind, maybe you've accidentally overwritten the innards of `buffer`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is a string.

Comment: @arne Yes, that could be an issue. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `StreamDecoderEncoder` object is a valid object? I.e. you're not using a null-pointer or a pointer/reference to an invalid object (e.g. pointer/reference to a local variable in another function)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was using the correct pointer. But I think there was garbage in the `buffer`. I used the clear() function and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: `(char *)data` have we verified 'data'? bad data can be a debugging nightmare. If you're trying to buffer data that might be incomplete, a string might be a bad tool.

Comment: Can you see the actual `data` it was concat'ing when it segfault? Another possibility is that your program has UB somewhere and it's manifesting itself here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem working on a school project a few months back... if a string gets massive, it can cause a segfault.  Try using something like an [ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/) instead.